# Python and Modbus

Tags: python, modbus

I am using modbus-tk to talk to a National Instruments cfp-1804 as a modbus tcp slave.  I am able to establish a socket connection with the cfp-1804.  Using wireshark, I can see both the master and slave acknowledge the connection.  When I send a request, the cfp acknowledges the request and closes the connection.  0 bytes of response are sent back.

Is there anything else that I can use to troubleshoot the request response?  I saw that function code 08 can perform diagnostics but I am not sure how to implement.  Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which kind of request do you send?  It can be not all function codes are implemented.  Read holding register (0x3) is probably implemented.

Comment: It ended up being a port issue. The device arbitrarily assigned itself to an open port. Once I forced it to 502 all the modbus commands worked perfectly. Funny how something so trivial can cause so much headache